# How to reclaim the disk space on ubuntu host after removing a big log file on a docker container

Tags: docker, diskspace

I removed a 10GB logfile from a running production docker container, but the free disk space on my ubuntu 18.04 host didn't change. As the container is running and I can not stop it, I think docker prune doesn't work for me. Am I right? So anyone can help me how to reclaim the disk space after deletion? Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Regards, Hamed!

Comment: In general, in Linux and other Unices, deleting a file doesn't release its disk space until all readers and writers have also closed.  If you delete the log file while Docker is still writing logs there, the file will still "exist" until you stop and delete the container.

Comment: Thank you @DavidMaze for the response. As I mentioned before, those containers are production wallets on the blockchain. So I can not stop them. It's strange if I can not free up space for deleted files on a running container.